# OCA8 Java Certification question - Java Operators

Tags: java, logical-operators

Came across this question in one of practice exam for OCA java certification:

**Which statements about the output of the following programs are true?**

```java
int i = 0;
boolean bool1 = true;

boolean bool2 = false;
boolean bool = false;
bool = (bool2 & method1("1")); //1
bool = (bool2 && method1("2")); //2
bool = (bool1 | method1("3")); //3
bool = (bool1 || method1("4")); //4
}

public static boolean method1(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);

    return true;
}
```

The answer given is it prints 1 and 3

Can some one please explain me the solution?

Comment: SO is not a code tutorial site.

Comment: A short google for "Java operators" will bring up [Oracle's own tutorial on operators in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), which also happens to have a super handy [list of operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).  From there it should be pretty straightforward to determine the difference between `&` and `&&`.  Hint: Short circuit logic means that the runtime stops evaluating the expression once it's clear that a particular branch will be taken.

Answer (score 3):

2 and 4 are not printed because only the first part of the expression is evaluated in those cases.

For the && Operator it doesnt matter what the second expression is, if the first expression is already false. So it is not necessery to evaluate the second part.

```
if(false && true)
```

is the same as

```
if (false)
```

For the || Operator it is vice versa, if the first expression is already true it is not necessary to evaluate the second part. Therefore your method is not called.

```
if(true || false)
```

is the same as

```
if(true)
```

But keep in mind that if you switch your expressions, like so:

```
bool = (method1("2") && bool2);
```

Your method would be called. Thats because your first part of the Expression is true, so the whole expression could be true. Therefore the second part needs to be evaluated too.

Try

```
bool = (method1("2") && method1("2") ); 
bool = (method1("2") || method1("2") );
```

and see what´s happening.

& and | are bitwise comparators and therefore every part of your expression is evaluated. Therefore your method is called.